# asp.net imagebutton access in listview

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i change imageUrl in listview function. I tried some codes but not worked.

my codes

```
protected void DoTheCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Button")
    {
        ImageButton img = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("Button1");
        img.ImageUrl = "/img/heartcirc.png";
```

html code

```
<asp:ListView ID="listUrunler" OnItemCommand="DoTheCommand" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 mb-4 mb-lg-0">
                        <div class=" card-img-top rounded shadow-sm border-0">
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" class="card-img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("urunResim") %>' PostBackUrl='<%# String.Format("UrunDetay.aspx?Id={0}",Eval("Id")) %>' />
                            <div class="card-body p-4">
                                <h5 class="card-title" style="margin-top: -20px"><%# Eval("urunBaslik") %></h5>
                                <div class="price text-success" style="justify-content: center; float: left;"><%# Eval("urunFiyat") %>TL</div>
                                <asp:ImageButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Width="20px" Height="20px" ImageUrl="/img/heart.png" CommandName="Button" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' Text="Add to Cart" />
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: So you need to replace image url when someone click on button ?

Comment: Hum, that looks to be ok. Open up the markup page, and drag in that image from the solution explore and see what the path name looks like in the mark up. What you have looks rather fine - and should work.

Comment: I was tried now with breakpoints. Paths changing but not saved . How can i save the paths on database or something